# Simple POST request using Spring Boot and AWS

Tags: java, spring, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to make a simple application that stores user data (name and password) into a database. To do this, I created EC2 and RDS instances. I run the Spring Boot application on EC2 which talks to RDS. My User class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to make GET and POST requests on EC2 localhost, so I added the necessary repository class:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "usertest", path = "usertest")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Now, I should be able to add an entry into my SQL database like so:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id": "102", username":"john", "password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8080/usertest
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
{"timestamp":1482172780645,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException","message":"could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet","path":"/usertest"}
```

I get the same message if I remove the "id" json field (since it should auto-increment).

I have an AppConfig class with configuration details for my RDS instance and the standard main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
}
```

I have also attached the security group needed for the EC2 instance to "talk" to the RDS instance. Any ideas why I can't make this simple POST? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is weird, I was expecting something like

```
Unexpected character
```

On of the problem is for sure in your curl, in your message you are missing the double quotes before username. The correct one is the following:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id": "102", "username":"john", "password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8080/usertest
```

I guess that you are executing the curl command in your ec2 instance, because you are using localhost:8080. Are you sure that you can reach the right database? Is your project working on your local environment (maybe using h2database)?

One more thing: you should check (and in case post) the stacktrace as first step, a message in a REST response is not enough.